# Move rows to new column if duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[What I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRaJA.png)

```
Sample_ID | fungi | fungi_ID | evalue | ITS_region
   A1       red      1112       0.7         1
   A1       red      1112       0.4         2
   B1       green    1234       0.03        1
   B1       blue     9090       0.02        2
```

to this:

```
Sample_ID | fungi | fungi_ID | evalue | ITS_region | dup_ITS | dup_fungi | dup_fungi_ID
   A1       red      1112       0.7         1              2       red           1112      
   B1       green    1234       0.03        1              2       blue          9090
```

I have parsed data from a NCBI blast into a pandas dataframe. However, all of the data have dupliate IDs (see attached), and I need the info from both IDS on the same line.

What I want to achieve is move the row data from the duplicates into new columns on the same line as the original.

The df contains the following headers (see attached): `sample_id`, `fungi`, `fungi_id`, `evalue`, `ITS region`

Comment: Please provide sample code in order to let us reproduce easily your problem.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Questions that ask for working code without showing effort are generally not well received.

Comment: Are there only two rows for each `Sample_ID`?

Comment: And welcome to Stack Overflow. You can check [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are only two rows for each `Sample_ID`, use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by columns  `Sample_ID` and get last values by [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.last.html). Then duplicates new columns are dropped by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)and index is reset by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print df

#  Sample_ID  fungi  fungi_ID  evalue  ITS_region
#0        A1    red      1112    0.70           1
#1        A1    red      1112    0.40           2
#2        B1  green      1234    0.03           1
#3        B1   blue      9090    0.02           2

print df.join(df.groupby('Sample_ID').last(), on='Sample_ID', rsuffix='_dup')
        .drop_duplicates(subset=['fungi_dup','fungi_ID_dup','ITS_region_dup','evalue_dup'])
        .reset_index(drop=True)

#  Sample_ID  fungi  fungi_ID  evalue  ITS_region fungi_dup  fungi_ID_dup  \
#0        A1    red      1112    0.70           1       red          1112   
#1        B1  green      1234    0.03           1      blue          9090   
#
#   evalue_dup  ITS_region_dup  
#0        0.40               2  
#1        0.02               2
```